# Tcl adds curly braces when using `$` sign

Tags: list, tcl, dollar-sign, braces

```
set B {pc_0::!mx_0 pi::$mx_0}
puts $B

set A ""
foreach x $B {
    lappend A $x
}

puts $A
```

The output of this program is

```
pc_0::!mx_0 pi::$mx_0
pc_0::!mx_0 {pi::$mx_0}
```

It is strange that tcl adds curly braces in second output. I guess it is because it uses `$` symbol. But I really need to use it and I don't want the braces to be inserted. How this can be explained and how to avoid the braces?

Comment: The braces are there only for grouping and avoiding a variable substitution. How are the braces being of any hindrance? If you're using $A as a list, you shouldn't get any problem when using the elements from $A.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a general rule, **don't treat lists as strings**. Pretend that they don't have a string representation. (The string representation is only useful for serialization, debugging, but not for the user).

To convert text (especially user-input) to a list use [`split`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/split.htm).
To convert it back, use [`join`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/join.htm).

Sou you want:

```
puts [join $A]
```

#### Background:

A [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/list.htm) have the sideeffect of escaping all meta-characters used by Tcl so no further subsitution takes place when you [`eval`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/eval.htm) this list. This is a very important property for generating Callbacks/code that will be later executed:

```
set userinput [gets stdin]
set code [list puts $userinput]
eval $code
```

No matter what the user enters here, the output is always the same as the user entered, without any substitution.

If the `$` would not be escaped, then an evaluation would try to substitute `$mx_0`, which will most likly fail.

Comment: The other way to get the words out of a string is `regexp -all -inline {\S+} $str`

Answer (score 0):

Why not print the list in a way similar to how it was created?

As an experienced programmer new to Tcl, this seems much more intuitive to me:

```
foreach x $A {
    puts $x
}
```