# Behaviour of list in TCL

Tags: list, tcl

I am working with a list (only one element) in my TCL code and when I print it out with puts I see that the text is sometimes enclosed with braces. ex: {abc} and sometimes its not. This causes problems because I am doing a regsub on this particular text and the brace causes my code to fail. I have also observed that the list is enclosed in braces when there are special symbols within the text.
Can anyone please explain why the list comes enclosed in braces.

Comment: Can you give an example? How do you access to your list content?

Comment: An example or two would make it a lot easier to advise you. Note that while a Tcl list can be used as a string, it is often problematic to use string commands such as `regsub` directly on lists for e.g. the reasons you note here. If you use the command `join` on the list, you will get a string that contains the same elements as the list but without the safeguarding braces.

Comment: The lesson is "use string commands on strings and list commands on lists"

Comment: What happens when you write `puts \"[lindex $myList 0]\"` ? Since your list is one element, that is probably what you want to use to get the contents.

Comment: Hi all, sorry for late reply.. Example: Lets say the "data" is "abc$" . When I do 'set idx [regsub -all {[^0-9a-zA-Z.-_]+} $data {_}]'  the idx is modified to '_abc_'  It should have been just 'abc_'   Whereas when the data is just "abc"  there are no issues of course since there are no special characters.

Comment: Also found what I was looking for here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020505/tcl-adds-curly-braces-when-using-sign

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When Tcl creates a list from individual values, it tries to use as little quoting as possible. If it is a simple value like `abc`, it omits all quoting characters. If it is a value with a metasyntax character like space in it (`abc def`), it encloses it in braces (`{abc def}`). If it is a value with unbalanced braces in (`abc{def`), it uses backslashes (`abc\{def`). This ensures that the lists that Tcl creates are always also understandable as scripts containing a single command whose words are exactly the element of the list.

It's not a good idea to use `regexp` on lists; the format is not really very friendly for that sort of work (and it's even worse when you consider everything that can be *parsed* as a list, which is a lot more than Tcl will actually ever generate from the `list` command). Extract the element (e.g., with `lindex` or `foreach`) and apply the regular expression to that.

Answer (score 1):

Values in tcl does not work the same way as in other languages. In tcl a list is just a string. A specially formatted string.

### Lists

The rules for a list is deceptively simple:

> A list is simply a string of words where each element of the list is a word separated by white space.

### Words

The word "word" above is tcl's definition of word, not the regular english definition:

> Whitespace separates words

Which implies that words are a continuous string of characters that are separated by whitespace. But also we have another rule:

> Words can be entirely enclosed in quotes to escape interpretation of whitespace

In other words, in tcl code:

```
# The following is a word:
hello

# The following is also a word, ONE word, not two:
"hello world"

# The following are TWO words:
say "hello world"
```

### Example of Lists

So from the above rules defining words, the following is an example of a list:

```
# This is a list of two elements:
"hello world"

# This is a list of one element:
"\"hello world\""
```

The reason the second list is one element is because we've quoted the two words `hello` and `world` with `""` therefore the tcl interpreter treats it as a single word.

### Quotes

Now comes the answer to `I see that the text is sometimes enclosed with braces`.

There are two ways to quote words/strings in tcl: `""` and `{}`. Double quotes work like they do in Perl and braces work like single quotes in Perl. That is, variables and functions are substituted within `""` but not within `{}`.

So the following two lists are exactly equivalent:

```
# List with one element:
{"hello world"}

# List with one element:
{{hello world}}
```

Interestingly, the two lists above are also equivalent to:

```
# List with one element:
{hello\ world}
```

since escaping the space character forces tcl to treat is as just an ordinary character and not a word separator.

Technically there's no official canonical form of what a list should look like if you try to treat it as a string. So the interpreter is free to insert `{}` or `\` or `""` if necessary. So don't treat lists as strings. Let tcl handle lists.

For example, to avoid regexp needing to handle `{}` characters you should use list operations to process the element you want:

```
set l {}
lappend l "hello world"
regexp {hello} [lindex $l 0]
```

If you need to search the list use `lsearch` instead of `regexp`:

```
lsearch -regexp $l {hello}
```