# Tcl: test for nested list

Tags: tcl

How can I efficiently test whether a Tcl list is nested (i.e. contains lists as elements)?

Based on https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Depth+of+a+list I constructed the following proc:

```
proc isNestedList {l} {
    return [expr ![string equal $l [concat {*}$l]]]
}
```

This gives the desired behavior (except for the case `{A}` which generally cannot be handled differently as far as I know, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66799916/3852630):

```
% isNestedList A
0
% isNestedList {A}
0
% isNestedList {{A}}
1
% isNestedList {A B}
0
% isNestedList {{A B}}
1
% isNestedList {A {B C}}
1
```

However, for long lists which are not nested, `isNestedList` is slow, probably due to the conversion from list to string. I tried a different version where I compare `$l` and `[concat {*}$l]` by `::struct::list equal` (https://tools.ietf.org/doc/tcllib/html/struct_list.html) to avoid this conversion, but that is even slower.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Note that this also breaks down for different forms or amounts of whitespace between list elements, e.g.     `isNestedList {A   B}` => `1`

Comment: A further note: putting { } around a single item does not magically make it a list, e.g.  
`set l {A {B} C}` => `A {B} C`  **but**  `% lappend l D` => `A B C D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that my earlier answer is overcomplicated and less than optimal.  I think this is better:

```
proc isNestedList l {
    foreach a $l {
        if {$a ne [lindex $a 0]} {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seems to work fine. The performance is about the same as with your earlier version (see my comment on your previous answer).

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the slowdown you mention, you need to stick to list operations, not string operations.  Here's one way:

```
proc isNestedList l {
    return [llength [lmap a $l {expr {[llength $a] > 1 ? 1 : [continue]}}]]
}
```

This uses `lmap` to filter the list down to only those elements which can themselves be treated as a list of more than one element, then checks if the resulting list is non-empty.

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot. There's one problem though: it doesn't recognize `{{A}}` as nested, but that's probably the case you mentioned in your comment. I also tested the performance on long lists. It is much faster than my version if the input is a long list which additional brackets, and it only requires about 70% of the time for a long list without additional brackets.

Comment: There's a difference; I think it is due to my sloppy definition of "nested". My version considers `{{{A B}}}` as nested, your's doesn't.

Comment: That's true, I'm only looking at the top level of sublists.  You would need some kind of recursive check to catch this case.

Comment: Actually I think replacing the `[llength $a] > 1` test with `$a ne [lindex $a 0]` will do the trick.  I will update my second answer to use this.